# Subtitle in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
Song *song = [self.music objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = song.title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = song.artist;

return cell;
```

I don't use Interface Builder. How I can make this cell to have a subtitle? All I get is a standard cell.

Comment: How are you registering your tableview with the identifier "Cell"?

Comment: `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

Comment: You'll need create a UITableViewCell subclass and in the init method (I think it's initWithStyle or something) you can do init the super with subtitle style.

Comment: Then register you subclass for the identifier.

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks.

Comment: your selected answer is using very old methods that have been updated to use registered classes. I down votes it because of this. You would be better using a subclass (especially for he future when you want to customise your cells).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. The old style approach is to not register any class, NIB or cell prototype, call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` without `forIndexPath`:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
       if (!cell) {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
       }

       Song *song = self.music[indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = song.title;
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = song.artist;

       return cell;
   }
   ```

   As we discussed elsewhere, this assumes that you do not register a class for that reuse identifier.
2. The alternative is to register your own class in `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   [self.tableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
   ```

   and then call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` *with* `forIndexPath` option, but lose the code that manually tests if it is `nil` (because it never will be `nil`):

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       Song *song = self.music[indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = song.title;
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = song.artist;

       NSLog(@"title=%@; artist=%@", song.title, song.artist); // for diagnostic reasons, make sure both are not nil

       return cell;
   }
   ```

   This obviously assumes that you've implemented a `UITableViewCell` subclass that includes the subtitle (note I'm overriding the style):

   ```
   @interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
   @end

   @implementation MyCell

   - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
       return [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   }

   @end
   ```

Personally, I think designing a cell prototype (which automatically registers the reuse identifier and takes care of all of this other stuff) is much easier. Even the old technique of registering a NIB is easier than the above. But if you want to do it entirely programmatically, those are the two approaches.

Comment: Yup, this is what I was trying to describe but on my phone at the moment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
UITableViewCell *cell= [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell==nil) {
  // Using this way you can set the subtitle 
  cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

Song *song = [self.music objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = song.title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = song.artist;

return cell;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I guess because cell is not nill after dequeue method

Comment: Unfortunatelly, with this code I get blank tableView

Comment: you get data successful in Song class? @starwars25

Comment: Yes, I do. I am sure with my data getter method evertything is OK, because I log output into console

Comment: Maybe I should use initWithStyle method istead of dequeue? The amount of RAM is large and I don't think that my several hundred cells will affect the device very hard. This code still produces the same output withou subtitle. Maybe I should construct a custom cell and use it? And how method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier can return nil if declaration says that it returns nonull?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",song.title); add this state ment in cell method and check any data is printed? @starwars25

Comment: The current code you provided outputs song titles but no subtitles.

Comment: you try without if condition. @starwars25

Comment: @starwars25 See his latest rendition. Note, also make sure that (a) you have not registered NIB/class for this reuse identifier and (b) the reuse identifier hasn't be used elsewhere in your code. But Dharmesh's current version is correct, so if this last rendition doesn't work, then you've got a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya No, I wouldn't try without `if` statement. Sure, make sure that `if` statement is getting called (my prior comment lists reasons why it might not), but don't lose `dequeue` functionality because he's got some other problem. starwars25 should fix that problem, not kludge around it.

Comment: Without if it works, but I assume that without if the cell will be allocated and initialized each time?

Comment: yes #Rob is correct because i use this code and always run successful. @starwars25

Comment: @starwars25 Yes, always calling `init` is inefficient, which is why you should (a) confirm if the if statement isn't getting called; and (b) then figure out why (and I provide two candidate reasons why this could be happening). Also, make sure that `artist` property isn't `nil`.

Comment: Maybe this line is wrong? `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

Comment: @starwars25 Yes, as I mentioned, if you're going to manually create it, you do *not* want to register the class.

Comment: Yeah, I understood. Now it is okay, but without indentifier the `if` statement is always called and the cell is always allocated.

Comment: Nothing. You're manually doing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps, but I think that this solution is less memory efficient than the dequeue method.